# Please help me with this limit of sequence: $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{3\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The question is from my homework.
It is to find the limit of the sequence as n approaches infinity:

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{3\sqrt{n}}$$

Please help! I have no idea how to approach this question.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try to plug in some (large) values of $n$ to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** your numerator, for every $n$, is bounded by the interval $[-1,1]$, while your denominator tends to infinity...

More rigorously:

**Theorem.** Let's assume that sequence $a_{n}$ has $k$ subsequences satisfying the following properties:

1. All of the subsequences converge to $g$;
2. Every term of $a_{n}$ belongs to one of those subsequences

Then $a_{n}$ also converges to $g$.

**Application:** let's choose two subsequences: $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$. We have:

$$a_{2n}=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}}\qquad a_{2n-1}=\frac{-1}{3\sqrt{n}}$$

We can easily notice that:

1. Every term of the sequence $a_{n}$ belongs to one of the above subsequences, and
2. Both $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n-1}=0$

Hence, the limit of $a_{n}$ is also $0$.

Comment: so isn't this limit zero?

Comment: @JadenQ - yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

While you would notice that numerator is bounded and denominator is not, hence $a_n$ could have only bounded value, this is not sufficient to have a limit. For having a limit, it should also be converging to some point and not bouncing back and forth between finite points, say +2 and -2. Luckily, +0 and -0 are the same thing, hence you would have limit in this case.

Comment: I still do not understand how to approach this question even though I do understand what you just said

Comment: @LieX - I don't understand your statement. If the numerator is bounded and the denominator is not, the sequence shouldn't be "bouncing back and forth between finite points" - either it will converge (if the denominator tends to some limit - let it even be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$), or the sequence will not be bounded at all (say, if the denominator is $(-2)^{n}$.

Comment: Though actually it should converge even in the second case too... What are the other options?